# PHP Wordpress dynamic custom image sizes

Tags: php, wordpress, image-size

wordpress has a good support for images in general.

to get new image sizes, one would just add some functions like :

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); //thumnails
set_post_thumbnail_size( 200, 120, true ); // Normal post thumbnails
add_image_size( 'single-post-thumbnail', 400, 300,False ); // single-post-test
add_image_size( 'tooltip', 100, 100, true ); // Tooltips thumbnail size
/// and so on and so on
```

my question is :

How can someone make those functions act in a dynamic manner , meaning that those sizes will be calculated on upload ?

for example - If I upload an image of 3000x4000 px - I would like my image sizes to be :

```
 add_image_size( 'half', 50%, 350%, False ); // Half the original
 add_image_size( 'third', 30%, 30%, true ); // One Third the original
```

Is there a way to do that ? where can I hook for that ?
Those image sizes are used registered in many functions -
Can someone think of an Uber-creative way to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wp_get_attachment_image_src to get downsized images of an attachement, in you case you only need to specify `add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' )` in your `functions.php` file then in your template do the following:

```
$id = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID)
$orig = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id)
$half = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, array($orig[1] / 2, orig[2] / 2))
$third = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id, array($orig[1] / 3, orig[2] / 3))
etc...
```

Comment: thanks for your answer . first - It is to be used in a plugin - not a theme . second - if I will use this method - the thumbs will not be created when uploaded , or am I wrong here ??

Comment: you can call `wp_get_attachment_image_src` in a plugin too. and yes, the resized images will be created the first time the method is called but I guess you can hook to `add_attachment` and create them just after the original is uploaded.

Comment: what's your point? if you hook to `add_attachment` and call the code above you will automatically create the 3 versions each time one picture is uploaded, which is actually what you would do with `add_image_size` if it was working your way, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use the filter `image_resize_dimensions`.

I have setup a new image with a strange width and height like so

```
add_image_size('half', 101, 102);
```

Then used the filter to half the image only when the half image size is being resized

```
add_filter( 'image_resize_dimensions', 'half_image_resize_dimensions', 10, 6 );

function half_image_resize_dimensions( $payload, $orig_w, $orig_h, $dest_w, $dest_h, $crop ){
    if($dest_w === 101){ //if half image size
        $width = $orig_w/2;
        $height = $orig_h/2;
        return array( 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $orig_w, $orig_h );
    } else { //do not use the filter
        return $payload;
    }
}
```