# How to dynamically set the width and height in the wordpress add_image_size function

Tags: php, wordpress

Similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9952360/php-wordpress-dynamic-custom-image-sizes), however this solution works only partially for me.

What I want to achieve is that when an admin uploads an image, four custom image sizes get registered with `add_image_size` function.
left-top, left-bottom, right-top, right-bottom. They must be perfect quarters.
Now the `add_image_size` function can take width and height, and it also takes array for crop position e.g.

`add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 220, array( 'left', 'top' ) ); // Hard crop left top`

but since uploaded images can vary in size and aspect ratio, I would need a way to set the width and height dynamically, or some way to use relative measurements.

I realise that images would end up in different sizes for the same custom "image-size", but I can handle it in my view with `wp_get_attachment_image_src` by setting a new size or with css.

I would very much appreciate your help on this.

Comment: what about to use thumbnails for these images? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_post_thumbnail_size

Comment: you can use responsive images by using picturefill https://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/

Comment: I may have not been entirely clear on what am I trying to achieve on the front end. Most of the uploads would be woocommerce product shots. My child theme's /single-product/product-image.php file would generate the view with main image as selected by admin as a product image and then next to it there should be four crops displaying quarters of that product image. Those quarters are generated and registered while uploading an image. 
I know there might be better ways but in this particular case it has to be this way...